# Notifications in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

In laravel, i am trying to send 4 different types of notifications to a user.Here is my part of code.

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="{{ url('/approvals/capexapproval') }}">
                            CAPEX
                            @if(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count()>0)
                  <span class="badge badge-light">
                  {{count(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications)}}
                  </span>
                @endif
              </a>
            </li>


                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="{{ url('/approvals/creditapproval') }}">
                            CUSTOMER
                            @if(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count()>0)
                 <span class="badge badge-light">
                 {{count(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications)}}
                 </span>
                 @endif
               </a>
             </li>

                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="{{ url('/approvals/vendorapproval') }}">
                            VENDOR
                            @if(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count()>0)
                 <span class="badge badge-light">
                   {{count(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications)}}
                  </span>
                @endif
               </a>
              </li>
```

For each menu I need to show the number of messages received and if I read a message of particular inbox the unread notifications count of that particular inbox should be decremented by 1.

Comment: Please mentioned what problem you're facing right now with this code

Comment: If I receive any message it shows the count as 1 in all the links

Comment: You are not separating your count on the notifications - so you are getting the count for all unread notifications and the count for one particular notification

Comment: Thank you @Josh Bolton.I did that too.But still the same